# in ejabberd, is it possible to specifiy a database schema name for a postgresql backend?

Tags: ejabberd

My scenario is hosting multiple domains (virtual hosts). The ejabberd doc says ...

> "Important note about virtual hosting: if you define several domains in ejabberd.yml (see
> section Host Names), you probably want that each virtual host uses a different
> configuration of database, authentication and storage, so that usernames do not conflict
> and mix between different virtual hosts."

I plan to host on AWS RDS, which means a lot of admin to onboard a new virtual host.

A simpler alternative would be for all virtual hosts to live in the same postgresql instance, but under individual schema names to create isolation within the db. Currently no schema is specified so tables are created under the default *public* schema.

Is this possible?

PS. I'm aware that the "new schema" supports multi-homing, but for the ease of admin I'd still prefer to keep each domain isolated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Well, your question is clear and specific. And the answer is, too: not possible, at least according to ejabberd documentation and implementation.

Comment: not the answer I was hoping for, but hey ho. 
I've add a feature request to https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/3500